# Defining `Thread#initialize`

Tags: ruby, multithreading

How can I define `Thread#initialize`? I tried the following:

(1)

```
class Thread
  def initialize
    super
    @foo = []
  end
end
Thread.new{}.join
```

(2)

```
class Thread
  def initialize &pr
    super(&pr)
    @foo = []
  end
end
Thread.new{}.join
```

(3)

```
class Thread
  def initialize
  end
end
Thread.new{}.join
```

but they return an error:

```
Uninitialized thread - check `Thread#initialize'.
```

Comment: You shouldn't be overriding the default Thread#initialize. What happens if you just use the built-in method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're destroying the original Thread.initialize when open up the class this way, the call to super is Object.initialize, not to what was previously in Thread.initialize.

It's similar to what is happening here:

```
class Dog
  def initialize
    puts 'Arf'
  end
end

class Dog
  def initialize
    super
    puts 'I did not arf'
  end
end
#dog.new  "I did not arf"
```

You could subclass Thread and then use super,  or you could use alias_method

```
class Thread
   alias_method :old_initialize, :initialize
   def initialize(*args,&blk)
     puts 'Before initialize'
     old_initialize(*args,&blk)
   end
end
```